# Isomorphism of two different extensions field

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Let $F$ be a field such that $\operatorname{Char} (F)\neq 2$.
Let $E,E'$ be extension fields of $F$ , $[E:F]=[E':F]=2$.

Prove $E,E'$ are $\text{$F$-isomorphism} \iff F^{\times}\cap (E^\times)^2 = F^{\times}\cap (E'^\times)^2.$

My attempt:

Suppose $E=F(a)$.

$$a^2 \in (E^\times)^2 \implies a^2=x+ay, \quad x,y\in F$$

Any idea ? Appreciate any help.

Comment: https://planetmath.org/quadraticextension

Comment: $E=F(a)$ does NOT imply that $a^2\in F$, so you need to figure out another approach. Example: $F=\Bbb{Q}$, $E=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$. If $a=1+\sqrt2$ we have $E=F(a)$ but $a^2\notin F$. Hint: Have you heard of the quadratic formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"$\Rightarrow$" Let $\sigma$ be the isomorphism, if $u=\alpha^2\in F^\times\cap (E^\times)^2$, then  $\sigma(u)=u=(\sigma(\alpha))^2\in F^\times\cap (E'^\times)^2$.

"$\Leftarrow$" Suppose $E=F(a)$ and $a^2=x+ay,x,y∈F$. Then $(a-1/2y)^2=x+1/4y^2\in F^\times\cap (E^\times)^2=F^\times\cap (E'^\times)^2$. So there is $b\in E'$, $(b-1/2y)^2=x+1/4y^2$. The element $b$ can not belong to $F$ since $a$ is not in $F$. Mapping $a$ to $b$ we get $E=F[a]\cong F[b]=E'$.

Comment: How you get $(a-1/2y)^2=x+1/4y^2\in F^\times\cap (E^\times)^2=F^\times\cap (E'^\times)^2$ from $a^2=x+ay,x,y∈F$ ?

Comment: $x+1/4y^2\in F^\times$, $(a-1/2y)^2\in (E^\times )^2$,  so $(a-1/2y)^2=x+1/4y^2\in F^\times\cap  (E^\times )^2$.